# Firebase Auth with Github login by using next-auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, next-auth

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import {
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithCredential,
    GithubAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../../../libs/firebase.config';
import getGithubToken from '../../../utils/getGithubToken';

// Dynamic 라우팅을 사용한는 이유는 signIn, callback, signOut을 자동으로 처리하기 위해서이다.

export const authOption: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID!,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRETS!,
        }),
    ],

    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token, user }: any) {
            session.user.username = session?.user?.name
                .split(' ')
                .join('')
                .toLocaleLowerCase();

            session.user.uid = token.sub;
            return session;
        },

        async signIn({ account, user, credentials }) {
            if (account?.provider === 'github') {
                const credential2 = GithubAuthProvider.credential(
                    account?.access_token as string,
                );

                try {
                    signInWithCredential(auth, credential2).then((res) => {
                        console.log('login success');
                    });
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            return false;
        },
    },

    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
};

export default NextAuth(authOption);
```

When i operate this code, firebase auth enroll my github account well, but my website push this error "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=AccessDenied 403 (Forbidden)"

i really can't find the answer.....

please help me